# Service not starting in Android from AlarmManager after app is closed

Tags: android, multithreading, service, alarmmanager, intentservice

Can anyone please correct my approach or suggest me the right ways for doing it.I have tried using broadcast receivers in place of services but that approach is not working for it.i.e I used getBroadcast() in place of getService() but didnt work.

It is working when the app is not closed from the application window but as soon as it is closed , the phone doesnt show notifications and ring as it was working in the case when the app wasn't closed.

> MainActivity.class

```
`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TimePicker timePicker;
    Button button;
    AlarmManager alarmManager;
    PendingIntent alarmIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        timePicker = findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                    calendar.set(
                            calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                            calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                            calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                            timePicker.getHour(),
                            timePicker.getMinute(),
                            0
                    );
                } else {
                    calendar.set(
                            calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                            calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                            calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                            timePicker.getCurrentHour(),
                            timePicker.getCurrentMinute(),
                            0
                    );
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyIntentService.class);
//This is the intent which will be fired
                alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
                Log.e("TAG:","AlarmSet.");
// Log is showing the right statement i.e the alarm was set but it wasnt triggered when the app was closed from the application window
            }
       });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.e("TAG","OnPause.");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.e("TAG","OnStop.");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e("TAG","OnDestroy.");
    }
}`
```

> IntentService.class

```
`public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {
 public MyIntentService() {
     super("MyIntentService");
 }

 @Override
 protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
     Log.e("TAG", "Starting service for notification and song");
     Random random = new Random();
     final Notification notification = new  NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "notify")
            .setContentTitle("New Notification")
            .setContentText("TIme for task.")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .build();
     final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
     notificationManager.notify(random.nextInt(), notification);
     MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
     mediaPlayer.start();

 }
}`
```

> Manifest file

`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".MyIntentService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />
 </application>

</manifest>`
```

Comment: on what api level are you testing this?

Comment: API level 23, what is the mistake ,please tell

Comment: @madking bro , you got anything ?